# Use jinja to change url pointer in css

Tags: django, django-views, django-templates, jinja2

I am building a website using Django, and I want to use the same template on two sites, but change the background color.

Currently in my **html** I have

```
<section>
    <div class="jumbotron jumbotron-fluid" id ="coverNytorv">
        <div class="container-fluid">
        
            <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md" id ="navbar">
                <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-light" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="#navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                </button>
                    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
                        <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
                            <li class="nav-item active">
                                <a class="nav-link px-5" id ="mainNavlink" href="#anchor_locations">LOCATIONS<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                            </li>
    
                            <li class="nav-item active">
                                <a class="nav-link px-5" id ="mainNavlink" href="#anchor-aboutUs">ABOUT US<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                            </li>
    
                            <li class="nav-item active">
                                <a class="nav-link px-5" id ="mainNavlink" href="#anchor-mainContact">CONTACT<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
            </nav>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

In the corresponding **css** I have

```
#coverNytorv {
    text-align: center; 
    align-items: center;
    background: url("media/cover.jpg") no-repeat center center;
    background-size: cover;
    min-height: 100%;
    justify-content: center;
    color: white;
    height: 700px;
    display: flex;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
}
```

I want to change the background image in the `view.py`. How should my `background` in css look like so that I can pass a path variable to the background image from the view.py? I imagine somehting like `{{ imagePath }}` in css `background`, and then in my `view.py` I could do something like `context = {'imagePath' : 'url_path_to_my_image'}`

Comment: Perhaps instead of rendering into css (should be static in my opinion) the simpler solution would be to render a class like `class="jumbotron jumbotron-fluid {{ background_class }}"` and have two different css classes for the different background images?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write inline css, for example you can change the coverNytorv div like below

```
 <div class="jumbotron jumbotron-fluid" id ="coverNytorv" style="background: url("'{{imagePath}}'")">
```

Simple as that! Also dont forget to remove background line from your style to avoid any confusion..

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I can't get it to work. The page is blank when I tried. Also I tried style="background-image: url('media/image.jpg');" using hard coding and there I only see a gray background but not the image

Comment: Have you checked the console in your browser? This might be related to django not being able to detect your file.. You can use the static tag!

Answer (score 0):

In html

```
<div class="jumbotron jumbotron-fluid" id ="coverNytorv" style="background-image: url({{imagePath}});">
```

In css

```
#coverNytorv {
    text-align: center; 
    align-items: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center center;
    background-size: cover;
    min-height: 100%;
    justify-content: center;
    color: white;
    height: 700px;
    display: flex;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
}
```

Then in views.py make sure that the imagepath is set to the relevant path